# Google Analytics Custom Dimension is not being populated

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I have the following code in my application to set the Google Analytics Custom Dimension (dimension1)

```
  var membNo = '123456789';
        var gafile = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
        var gaKey = 'UA-XXXXXXX-3';

        (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] ||
                    function() {
                        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
                    },
                i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
        })(window, document, 'script', gafile, 'ga');


            ga('create',
                'UA-XXXXXXX-3',
                'auto');

        if (membNo.length > 0) {
            ga('set', 'dimension1', membNo);
        }
        ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);
```

In GA, I have created the custom dimension (scope: user) 1 day ago but still cannot see anything coming through

How long exactly is the lag before custom dimensions come through? I am confident I have set the diimension correctly before sending any `pageview` or `event`

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Where do you have this piece of code? Is it on every single page? Are there situations where membNo would be null,undefined?

Comment: @XTOTHEL - this piece of code is on every page and through the Google Analytics extension in Chrome I can see that dimension1 is set to the value I want on every pageview and event send

Comment: Hi Mike, if that’s the case, I think try waiting a little longer. Your code is correct.

Comment: can you check your network log, filter by collect and check the pageview hits contains dimension? If yes, and you are on GA free, then it can take utp 24-72 hrs for the data to show in reports

Comment: @Tushar - many thanks. They have now started coming through so it was the delay (thanks for the info re: up to 72 hours)